# Pandas counter as a new column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, counter

I'm trying to build a dataframe in which I'm gonna build a timeline chart. On the X-axis I'm gonna have the dates and on the Y-axis I'm gonna have the amount if a specific ID.

Here is my attempt:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


file = ('test31.csv')

df = pd.read_csv(file)
df = df[['ID', 'Created Date', 'Finished Date']]

df.head()

Output:

ID        Created Date      Finished Date

XY11           2020-07-21          2020-07-23
AA12           2020-07-17          2020-07-28
AA12           2020-07-15          2020-07-20
AA12           2020-07-15          2020-07-23
XY11           2020-07-13          2020-07-22
```

Now I'm gonna count how many ID's was created one a specific date.

```
x = df.groupby(['ID', 'Created Date'])['Created Date'].size().to_frame('size1')
print(x)

Output:

ID             Created Date        size1

XY11           2020-07-21          1
XY11           2020-07-13          1

AA12           2020-07-15          2
AA12           2020-07-17          1
```

What I'm lacking here is the counter column, which should increase as new ID's are created.
After I've managed to do that, I'm gonna subtract the Finished Date counter and build a timeline based on that. Perhaps there is an easier way for this but this is the plan I got at the moment.

Wanted output:

```
ID             Created Date        size1          counter

XY11           2020-07-21          1              1
XY11           2020-07-13          1              2
XY11           2020-08-14          5              7

AA12           2020-07-15          2              2
AA12           2020-07-17          1              3
```

EDIT:

I'm probably gonna have to sort by date, but that's a problem for later.

UPDATE:

With some help from the community I now got this:

```
x = df.groupby(['ID', 'Created Date'])['Created Date'].size().to_frame('size1')
y = df.groupby(['ID', 'Finished Date'])['Finished Date'].count().to_frame('size2')

x['counter1'] = x.groupby('ID').size1.cumsum()
y['counter2'] = y.groupby('ID').size2.cumsum()

print(x)
print(y)

x Output:

ID             Created Date        size1          counter1

XY11           2020-07-21          1              1
XY11           2020-07-13          1              2
XY11           2020-08-14          5              7

AA12           2020-07-15          2              2
AA12           2020-07-17          1              3


y Output

ID             Finished Date       size2          counter2

XY11           2020-07-28          1              1
XY11           2020-09-13          4              5
XY11           2020-08-14          1              6

AA12           2020-10-15          6              6
AA12           2020-11-17          2              8
```

How can I subtract counter1 with counter2 only where the date matches?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```py
x['counter'] = x.groupby('ID').size1.cumsum()
print(x)
```

Output

```
     ID Created Date  size1  counter
0  XY11   2020-07-21      1        1
1  XY11   2020-07-13      1        2
2  AA12   2020-07-15      2        2
3  AA12   2020-07-17      1        3
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I was looking for! Now I'm just gonna have to figure out how to subtract with the Finished Date counter. I can't subtract row for row, but only where the date matches. Thanks!